# Jquery same functionality for different class selectors

Tags: jquery, function

I have two html elements . The first one is class edits and the second is edits2. I wish to run a script with the same functionality for both classes but with different variables

HTML

```
<i data-orderid="<?php echo $row['order_id']; ?>" class="edits fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>

<i data-orderid="<?php echo $row['order_id']; ?>" class="edits2 fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
```

Jquery

```
$('.edits').click(function(event) {
  .... Do something...});

$('.edits2').click(function(event) {
  .... Do something...});
```

Is there a way have one script that depending on the class selector perfoms the function or do I need to write different scripts for each element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind the clicks to a function you have defined, instead of an anonymous function...

```
function edit(){ /* ... */ }
$('.edits, .edits2').on("click", edit);
```

**Edit:** Not sure if I understood, you can also look for the class within your function with

```
if($(this).hasClass( "edits2" )){
  //edits 2 code
}else{
  //edits code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function within the clicks of both elements...

```
function myFunction() {
    //work here 
};
$('.edits').click(function (event) {
    myFunction();
    //do more here...
});
$('.edits2').click(function (event) {
    myFunction();
    //do more here...
});
```